# Disconnect UDP socket in python?

Tags: python, sockets, network-programming, udp

I need to 'disconnect' a UDP socket in python(and not close it!).

Is it possible to do the equivalent of:

```
int disconnect_udp_sock(int fd)
{
    struct sockaddr_in sin;        

    memset((char *)&sin, 0, sizeof(sin));
    sin.sin_family = AF_UNSPEC;
    return (connect(fd, (struct sockaddr *)&sin, sizeof(sin)));
}
```

taken from [here](http://timesinker.blogspot.com/2010/02/unconnect-udp-socket.html) in python without interfacing the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at socketmodule.c in the Python 2.7 sources, it doesn't seem possible.  You really need to define and call the C function above.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, although I hoped for some kind of a neat hack :-) I'll stick with C for now.

Comment: Note, with http://cffi.readthedocs.org/: `import cffi; ffi=cffi.FFI(); ffi.cdef("int disconnect_udp_sock(int fd);"); lib=ffi.verify("..paste the code of the C function above with a couple needed #includes..")`.  Then you can use `lib.disconnect_udp_sock()`.