# UDP 'disconnect' in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, network-programming

I've found an earlier question from 2013, stating that in Python 2.7 it is not possible. ([Disconnect UDP socket in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16828171/disconnect-udp-socket-in-python)).

So, is that still the case in 3.8+?

I've tried all sorts of things, ranging from `my_udp_socket.connect(None)` to `my_udp_socket.connect(('127.0.0.1', 0))` but to no avail.

Can someone please confirm this?

Comment: There is nothing like a UDP socket. UDP is socketless.

Comment: @KlausD. Yet python uses its sockets API to send data over UDP. Java does something similar, e.g. `DatagramSocket`. Perhaps you mean to write "connection" and "connectionless".

Comment: Can you explain what such a capability might be useful for? If I can up with a proposed solution how would you test it to see if it really works? A code example showing what you would do if, say, `my_udp_socket.connect(('127.0.0.1', 0))` actually worked would be illustrative. Note that python has the `connect_ex` method which at least won't throw an exception.